# Book series about a boy bonded to a phoenix

Tags: story-identification, books, novella

It was about a boy who is sort of bonded to a Phoenix. He can communicate telepathically with her. He goes on some sort of quest and meet some other kids who are bonded with these other magical creatures: a sabre tooth tiger, a winged wolf, a giant snake.

The kid bonded with the snake was not quite an ally at first and the main group was wary of him. There was some scenes in a mine I think. At the end they battle this dude at a volcano that wants all of the creatures for himself.

The Phoenix gets hurt and she falls in the lava and the characters think she’s dead, but she comes back stronger because it’s lava and she is strengthened by fire. I think there were four books in the series.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Boy has some relationship to a phoenix and there's an evil guy with a giant snake? _Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets_? :D (just kidding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Chronicles of Avantia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Avantia) by Adam Blade

Wikipedia's description of the first book, *First Hero*:

> Avantia stands on the edge of an abyss. Dark armies, led by a
>   malevolent warlord, are mustering on its borders. But destiny has
>   chosen an unlikely hero to fight the threat… 15-year-old Tanner is no
>   ordinary boy. Son of a murdered father, and abducted mother, his life
>   is steeped in tragedy. As the "Chosen Rider" of a ferocious young
>   flame bird called Firepos, it is up to him to turn the tide of war
>   that threatens to engulf the land.